# How to send email of the Excel worksheet from Excel for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I want to send out automatic email from excel at a specific time in the day daily with the worksheet as message in the email body. I'm using Excel for Mac, but I'm unable to find Send Email to Recipient option in this. Neither are the following vba scripts working:

```
Function MailFromMacwithOutlook(bodycontent As String, mailsubject As String, _
            toaddress As String, ccaddress As String, bccaddress As String, _
            attachment As String, displaymail As Boolean)



    Dim scriptToRun As String

    scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "tell application " & _
                  Chr(34) & "Microsoft Outlook" & Chr(34) & Chr(13)

    scriptToRun = scriptToRun & _
     "set NewMail to make new outgoing message with properties" & _
       "{content:""" & bodycontent & """, subject:""" & mailsubject & """}" & Chr(13)

    If toaddress <> "" Then scriptToRun = scriptToRun & _
       "make new to recipient at NewMail with properties" & _
       "{email address:{address:""" & toaddress & """}}" & Chr(13)

    If ccaddress <> "" Then scriptToRun = scriptToRun & _
       "make new cc recipient at NewMail with properties" & _
       "{email address:{address:""" & ccaddress & """}}" & Chr(13)

    If bccaddress <> "" Then scriptToRun = scriptToRun & _
       "make new bcc recipient at NewMail with properties" & _
       "{email address:{address:""" & bccaddress & """}}" & Chr(13)

    If attachment <> "" Then
     scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "make new attachment at NewMail with properties" & _
              "{file:""" & attachment & """ as alias}" & Chr(13)
    End If

    If displaymail = False Then
        scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "send NewMail" & Chr(13)
    Else
        scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "open NewMail" & Chr(13)
    End If
    scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "end tell" & Chr(13)

    If Len(toaddress) + Len(ccaddress) + Len(bccaddress) = 0 Or mailsubject = "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no To, CC or BCC address or Subject for this mail"
        Exit Function
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        MacScript (scriptToRun)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Function

Function MailFromMacWithMail(bodycontent As String, mailsubject As String, _
           toaddress As String, ccaddress As String, bccaddress As String, _
                attachment As String, displaymail As Boolean)



    Dim scriptToRun As String

    scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "tell application " & _
                  Chr(34) & "Mail" & Chr(34) & Chr(13)

    scriptToRun = scriptToRun & _
         "set NewMail to make new outgoing message with properties " & _
            "{content:""" & bodycontent & """, subject:""" & _
               mailsubject & """ , visible:true}" & Chr(13)

    scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "tell NewMail" & Chr(13)

    If toaddress <> "" Then scriptToRun = scriptToRun & _
       "make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties " & _
       "{address:""" & toaddress & """}" & Chr(13)

    If ccaddress <> "" Then scriptToRun = scriptToRun & _
       "make new cc recipient at end of cc recipients with properties " & _
       "{address:""" & ccaddress & """}" & Chr(13)

    If bccaddress <> "" Then scriptToRun = scriptToRun & _
       "make new bcc recipient at end of bcc recipients with properties " & _
       "{address:""" & bccaddress & """}" & Chr(13)

    If attachment <> "" Then
        scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "tell content" & Chr(13)
        scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "make new attachment with properties " & _
                      "{file name:""" & attachment & """ as alias} " & _
                      "at after the last paragraph" & Chr(13)
        scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "end tell" & Chr(13)
    End If

    If displaymail = False Then scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "send" & Chr(13)
    scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "end tell" & Chr(13)
    scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "end tell"

    If Len(toaddress) + Len(ccaddress) + Len(bccaddress) = 0 Or mailsubject = "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no To, CC or BCC address or Subject for this mail"
        Exit Function
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        MacScript (scriptToRun)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Function

Function KillFileOnMac(Filestr As String)


'The VBA Kill command on a Mac will not work with long file names(28+ characters)
    Dim ScriptToKillFile As String
    ScriptToKillFile = ScriptToKillFile & "tell application " & Chr(34) & _
                       "Finder" & Chr(34) & Chr(13)
    ScriptToKillFile = ScriptToKillFile & _
                       "do shell script ""rm "" & quoted form of posix path of " & _
                       Chr(34) & Filestr & Chr(34) & Chr(13)
    ScriptToKillFile = ScriptToKillFile & "end tell"

    On Error Resume Next
    MacScript (ScriptToKillFile)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

And this:

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Excel2011_1()
'For Excel 2011 for the Mac and Apple Mail
'Note: The workbook must be saved once
    Dim wb As Workbook

    If Val(Application.Version) < 14 Then Exit Sub

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    With wb
        MailFromMacwithOutlook bodycontent:="Hi there", _
                    mailsubject:="Testing", _
                    toaddress:="something@something.com", _
                    ccaddress:="", _
                    bccaddress:="", _
                    attachment:=.FullName, _
                    displaymail:=True
    End With
    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Could anyone help me with how this can be done in Excel for mac?